# React: Trigger onSubmit of form from parent

Tags: reactjs, ref

In my parent component I am creating a ref and passing it to child -

```
<ChildComponent ref={submitRef}/>
```

In my ChildComponent, I have a form whose onSubmit should be triggered when I click a button in the parent.

```
<form onSumit={handleOnSubmit}>
    <Button type="submit" ref={submitRef}/>
</form>
```

Something seems wrong with this code as it's not working. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score -1):

I went through similar error or exception case. While using ref inside child components, we have to forward the ref to track the changes. You can have a look at the [forward ref](https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html) at react docs.

- Parent Container

Parent Container need to be like this:

```
import React from "react";
import { useRef } from "react";
import ChildComponent from "./ChildComponent";

const ParentContainer = () => {
  const submitRef = useRef();

  return <ChildComponent ref={submitRef} />;
};

export default ParentContainer;
```

- Child component

Inside child component, we have to accept ref. Also we need to create a forward component with the help of ForwardRef. It will through new component. Now, we have to export this new component. The code goes like this

```
import React from "react";

const ChildComponent = (props, ref) => {
  const handleOnSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
  };
  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleOnSubmit}>
      <button type="submit" ref={ref}>
        Submit
      </button>
    </form>
  );
};

const ForwordComponent = React.forwardRef(ChildComponent);

export default ForwordComponent;
```